# GNU MAKE exception with shell command

Tags: windows, path, makefile, gnu

I'm running make on my project on WIN7 PC and getting the following error:

```
make: Interrupt/Exception caught (code = 0xc0000005, addr = 0x0040b0ac)
```

when removing some make parts it seems as the following line is the problematic:

```
$(shell if exist $(1) echo YES)
```

Any ideas what seems to be the issue? solutions?

Thanks!

**Update:**

I'm working with gnu make 3.81.1 mingw32 , same make and makefile used to work on my previous WIN XP (32 bit), problem appeared after upgrading to WIN7 .

Comment: I do not get this crash for mingw32-make 3.82.90 on Windows 7, assuming I would get it by defining e.g. `yes = $(shell if exist $(1) echo YES)` and then invoking e.g. `$(call yes,Makefile)`. Upgrade Mingw32?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I think I've got it.

Apparantly it is something related to the PATH, if I replace the "shell" command with a predefined :

```
 _SHELL=C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe
```

the problem is fixed. might be because of severl c:\Program Files PATH instances .

Upgrading to 3.82 fixes the issue as well so I guess the've fixed that

Thanks!

Comment: You should accept your own answer in order to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways GNU make can be built for windows, and the different ways will use different shells for the `$(shell ...)` command.  I don't actually know if any of them will ever invoke Windows command.com or not.

But in any event, it doesn't seem like your version of GNU make works properly in that way.  You should update your question with where you got your GNU make from (cygwin?  mingw?) or how you built it, if you built it yourself.

Also you might ask on the make-w32@gnu.org mailing list, where Windows users of GNU make hang out.